# Parser for json Object in java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am trying to create a common parser in java.I am passing json object from different class based on my need.But parsing doesnot works for me.Can anybody help me to make a JSONObject parser in java.Any help will be highly appreciable....

This is my code for common parser

```
public JSONObject jsonParser(JSONObject objJson){
        //JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(objJson);
        JSONArray the_json_array = objJson.getJSONArray("profiles");
        JSONObject SnapshotRequest= objJson.g;
        Iterator x = SnapshotRequest.keys();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        while (x.hasNext()){
            String key = (String) x.next();
            jsonArray.put(songs.get(key));
        }

}
```

In this code I am getting an error that need to cast.

`JSONArray the_json_array = objJson.getJSONArray("profiles");`

But casting won't work.

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an exception? It would help if you described *how* it does not work

Comment: If you are getting an error, please add the full stack trace to your question

Comment: @Dragondraikk there is no stack trace because i cannot run it, the code itself had exception
Can you provide some code for parsing json object

Comment: So provide the exact compile error. Likely you have two different JSON parsing libraries on your classpath and you're mixing up classes from both, but nobody can say for certain until you stop hiding the actual specific error details.